# Monotonically decreasing sequence/series proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a proof that I'm working on and it goes like this:

Assume $a_k > 0$ and $a_k$ is monotonically decreasing. Show that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k < \infty \iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k < \infty$$

where $b_k = 2^k a_{2^k}$

My problem is that I don't know where I can start versus what I have to show beforehand. Do I start by showing that since $a_k > 0$ and it is monotonically decreasing, then we also *assume* that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k < \infty$ and use that assumption to get to the RHS of the relationship?

I'm still fairly new to proofs, so I'm not sure, but think that this is how it works.

However, I don't have much of a good idea on how to show that the left-hand side is true only if the right hand side is true.

Any and all help and encouragement is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea what the name of the test was called.